# How to use saved disk game data on a different version of the same game?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, fifa-19, ea-sports-active

I had an EA Sports FIFA 19 disk (CD) that I had bought after playing. There were a lot of saved games on it. Then the CD cracked because I dropped it. So I decided to purchase the same game on the PSN store, but, once it got downloaded, it wasn't showing the saved data that I had already accumulated. 

What can I do about this?